# Trouble passing "pointer to a function" to pthread_create in C++

Tags: c++, pthreads, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

Please read the complete question before considering this a duplicate.

I have worked on `pthread_create()` in C which accepts its third argument as "pointer to a function which returns void pointer and takes void pointer as an argument".

i.e., the third argument of `pthread_create` is `void *(*routine)(void *)`

So, I just got an idea to use `pthread_create()` in C++. The function `print()` which I want to pass to `pthread_create()` is a member of a class shown below.

**Daemon.cpp**

```
#include "Daemon.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

Daemon::Daemon() {
}

Daemon::~Daemon() {
}

void *Daemon::print(void *args){
    cout << Hello World" << endl;
    return NULL;
}
```

To take advantage of object oriented design of C++, I put the `pthread_create()` in a class `Thread`. This is shown below:

**Thread.cpp**

```
#include "Thread.h"
using namespace std;

Thread::Thread( void *(Daemon::*routine)(void *), Daemon& dmObj ) {
    this->thread = 0; //pthread_t thread;
    this->obj = dmObj;// Daemon obj;
    this->functionPointer = routine; // void *(Daemon::*functionPointer)(void *);
}

Thread::~Thread() {

}

int Thread::createThread(){
    //(this->obj.*this->functionPointer)(NULL);
    pthread_create(&this->thread, NULL, (this->obj.*this->functionPointer), NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

To get above classes working, I called them from `main()` like shown below:

**subsfind.cpp**

```
int main(void) {
    Daemon dm;

    Thread t1( &Daemon::print, dm);
    t1.createThread();
}
```

If I enable the fourth last line of **Thread.cpp**, i.e., `(this->obj.*this->functionPointer)(NULL);`, the output shows as `Hello World`.
This means that, above codes pass pointer to a function just fine.
But, I could not pass this function `print()` (which is a member of a class) to `pthread_create()`.
The compiler error is:

```
Thread.cpp: In member function ‘int Thread::createThread()’:
Thread.cpp:39:72: error: invalid use of non-static member function
pthread_create(&thread, NULL, (this->obj.*this->functionPointer), NULL);
```

I am beginner in C++ and I don't know what must I do to get this working. Perhaps I need to cast the object of class `Daemon` to static or declare `print()` as static. I tried both of the methods but it didn't work. May be, I am doing it wrong or missing something.

Any idea on this?

Comment: Why don't you just pass a `std::function` and you pass `pthread_create` `target`?

Comment: @black: You can't pass `std::function` to `pthread_create()`.

Comment: I read your question, and it's very well a duplicate as marked now. The answer is given there.

Comment: I couldn't find the question. You found it for me. You're awesome. Thanks :)

Comment: Hi. I have some findings which contradicts to the answers given in the original question. If I provide such findings, would you unmark this question from being duplicate?